# MySQL how to partition list for uncertain value?

Tags: mysql, partition

For example, the data:

```
id  fruits
1   apple
2   banana
3   uncertain_1
4   uncertain_2
```

I now want to partition the fruits column

```
Alter Table fruits_table 
PARTITION BY list (fruits) 
(
PARTITION p_apple VALUES IN ('apple'),
PARTITION p_banana VALUES IN ('banana'),
PARTITION p_other VALUES NOT IN ('apple','banana')
);
```

But it looks like the SQL will have synax error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this kind of partitioning is not useful

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Sorry, just found the list type required INT value on that column. When I think of partition, my data has huge on "apple" & "banana" type, so I want to seperate them, expect it wouldn't affect other query on "uncertain" type

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code, as you can see when reading [the documentation for MySQL `LIST` Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-partitioning-excerpt/8.0/en/partitioning-list.html):

1. `PARTITION BY LIST` only allows integer values, not strings
2. There is no catch-all `NOT IN` option: each partition must be defined with the `VALUES IN (...)` syntax, meaning that you need to list all possible values.

One solution would be to create a separate table to reference all possible fruits, like:

```
fruit_id        fruit_name
1               apple
2               banana
3               uncertain
```

Then, you can refer to this reference table in your real table with a foreign key, so you get something like:

```
id    fruit_id
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
```

Now you can use partitioning:

```
ALTER TABLE fruits_table PARTITION BY list (fruit_id) (
    PARTITION p_apple  VALUES IN (1),
    PARTITION p_banana VALUES IN (2),
    PARTITION p_other  VALUES IN (3)
);
```

Comment: Yes. found that problems. Then any method to achieve that? I want to seperate uncertain with "apple" & "banana"

Comment: probably, I have to add one more INT column